# Unable to resolve type: System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version 4.0.0.0 - Asp.net Core (.net core 2.1) server, .NET 4.6.1 Client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, protobuf-net

I've got a legacy client application written in .net 4.6.1 consuming data of a WCF server.
I am trying to replace the WCF server with an ASP.NET Core application and Protobuf serialization.
I am using libraries:

- [Protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) in both the client and server for serialization/de-serialization
- [Core WebApi Formatters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Protobuf/) in the server

Trying in the client side to deserialize the returned content like below:

```
var resultData = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ExcelDropdownNode>(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

But I am getting an error in the protobuf library:

> Unable to resolve type: System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e (you can use the TypeModel.DynamicTypeFormatting event to provide a custom mapping)

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

As a side note, I have to return dynamic data in the server and protobuf isn't very happy about it. I have marked a `List<object>` property with `DynamicType=True` and changing all ValueTypes to string (i.e 4 -> "4"). This allowed the serialization on the server-side to work.

The dynamic property in the ExcelDropDownCode is as below:

```
[ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
public List<object> DataItems
{
    get { return dataItems; }
    set { dataItems = value; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you used a Full Framework library on a .NET Core project. That Full library is trying to find the Full Framework string type and fails. Which packages, references did you add to the project?

Comment: I believe that if I had used a full framework library in the .net core server, the error would have been in the server. In the server-side it works just fine. It is the client-side that gives me the error. Packages are: protobuf-net in client and server, different compilations for both.

Comment: Don't try dynamic type serialisation between different frameworks (net/core) since in your case, the types don't exist in the other framework (different type identity). Try using "any" or extensions in your protobuf definitions.

Comment: As for replacing WCF with Protobuf, what do you mean? WCF is *primarily* used for SOAP services. It doesn't just format messages, it implements a lot of the WS-* interoperability standards like security, addressing, attachements, etc. Protobuf isn't used in SOAP services at all. Protobuf is useful if you want to create your own services from scratch

Comment: @gpanagopoulos there's no ambiguity about that error. Somehow, somewhere you tried to use a Full Framework assembly in a .NET Core project. Please post the *full* package names and versions, so people can search for them in NuGet and see whether they support Full, .NET Core or .NET Standard

Comment: I am replacing the full WCF service, rewriting it as an asp.net core web service (I am not changing the WCF component to use protobuf) Martin thanks, I will give it a try as per your suggestion.

Comment: Looks there was a similar issue in the [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/387) repo as Marc Gravell says there, `Do you have a minimal example of the setup here? I suspect the detail
matters.`. At the very least `ExcelDropdownNode`.

Comment: Another very important point - *why* do you want to return dynamic data. WCF doesn't like that either. WCF does allow service payloads to contain multiple types but that information is always known in advance and specified in the service's WSDL/XSDs. It would be impossible for clients and servers to work together otherwise. The modern equivalent is an OpenAPI/Swagger specification

Comment: Edited the post with the code that seems if I exclude the serialization and deserialization works. It is the nature of the system that requires me to return dynamic data. I also have to avoid big changes in the contracts of the new service and keep to a minimum the regression testing in the legacy client system.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. Managed to solve by overriding the type resolution.

Comment: This is very useful and interesting, thanks; ah, the joys of `DynamicType`... I need to think about whether I can automate any of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve by adding in the client side the type resolution code below:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.DynamicTypeFormatting += (sender, args) => {
if (args.FormattedName.Contains("System.String, System.Private.CoreLib"))
{
    args.Type = typeof(string);
}};
```