# Response from SignalR being interrupted?

Tags: c#, async-await, json.net, thread-safety, signalr

I am trying to set up SignalR for my Xamarin App. Well got this working for small plain strings, so in general I think my setup is okay-ish. But for some reason this does not work for "bigger" (well 400 characters) serialized objects (using Newtonsoft JSON).

It's strange: when I debug it I can step to the bold (eww, two stars) line... and after that just... well nothing happens - no Exception, no Log. I just cannot step to the italic (...one star) line (and also no additional line in the log is created). And the App is not crashing or whatever.

Well I guess it's something timing related, but after spending 4-5 hours I have no idea what to try next.

```
    private HubConnection HubConnection { get; set; }
    
    /// setting up connection and subscribe
    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        Log.Debug("Create connection to hub");
        HubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .WithUrl($"{ServiceLocator.Defaults.BackendUrl}MainHub")
            .Build();

        HubConnection.On<string>("ResponseFromHub", DefaultHandler);

        await HubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    /// should handle incoming data
    private async Task DefaultHandler(string requestContextString)
    {
        Log.Debug($"Response {requestContextString}");
        // everything seems to work until the next line
        **var requestContext = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<RequestContext>(requestContextString);**
        *Log.Debug($"Response as object {requestContext}");*    
        await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    
    /// send a request
    public async Task Request(RequestContext rc)
    {
        if (HubConnection == null)
            await Initialize();


        var requestContextString = SerializationHelper.SerializeObject(rc);
        Log.Debug($"Request: {rc}");
        await HubConnection.InvokeAsync(
            "RequestFromHub", 
            requestContextString
        );
    }
```

The SerializationHelper is just a wrapper around the default Newtonsoft functions, which just sets the options (what I used like thousand of times):

```
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string contentString, JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = null)
    {
        if (jsonSerializerSettings == null)
        {
            jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            jsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple;
            jsonSerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ObjectDeserializer(), new IntDeserializer(), new FloatDeserializer() };
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(contentString, jsonSerializerSettings);
    }
```

**Update**
Seems like it has something to do with the serializer. I was able to make it work using other settings for TypeNameHandling (well not using TypeNameHandling.All). But this does not fix the problem, because I need the type information for object deserialization.
I guess it is some threading related problem, and the thread is locked??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem after changing the default Exception handling in the debugger:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide

Indeed there is an Exception, which was just silenced!

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib
```

So the next steps would be to find a way around that. I am using a .NET Standard and a .NET 5 ("core") library. But that's another topic and is discussed, e.g. here: [Unable to resolve type: System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version 4.0.0.0 - Asp.net Core (.net core 2.1) server, .NET 4.6.1 Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391825/unable-to-resolve-type-system-string-system-private-corelib-version-4-0-0-0)